# Why TForm's _release does not call destructor?

Tags: delphi, interface, vcl, delphi-2006

Why TForm's  _release method does not call destructor?

```
var
   F, U : IUnknown;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  U := IUnknown(TMyObject.Create);    // MyIterfacedObject (inherits TInterfacedObject)
  F := IUnknown(TMyForm.Create(nil)); 
end;

procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  U := nil;    // Calls destructor
  F._Release;  // Does not call destructor
  F := nil;    // Does not call destructor
end;
```

I took a look at _release methods of TInterfaceObject and TComponent classes:

```
function TInterfacedObject._Release: Integer;
begin
  Result := InterlockedDecrement(FRefCount);
  if Result = 0 then
    Destroy;
end;
```

---

```
function TComponent._Release: Integer;
begin
  if FVCLComObject = nil then
    Result := -1   // -1 indicates no reference counting is taking place
  else
    Result := IVCLComObject(FVCLComObject)._Release;
end;
```

TInterfacedObject's _release seems quite intelligible, but what TComponent's _release do? Seems weird to me...

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `TComponent` adopts the policy that lifetime management is the responsibility of the user of the class, and is not to be managed automatically by any interface references taken. That policy is expressed clearly in `TComponent._Release`.

```
function TComponent._Release: Integer;
begin
  if FVCLComObject = nil then
    Result := -1   // -1 indicates no reference counting is taking place
  else
    Result := IVCLComObject(FVCLComObject)._Release;
end;
```

The common scenario, the one which you describe, has `FVCLComObject` equal to `nil`. And so the code explicitly says that there is no reference counting by returning `-1`. It's even commented that way.

Lifetime management needs to be done one way or another. The two commonly used patterns with Delphi code are:

**Lifetime managed by caller**

```
var
  obj: TMyObject;
....
obj := TMyObject.Create;
try
  DoSomething(obj);
finally
  obj.Free; // the object is explicitly destroyed here
end;
```

Although, `TComponent` is often used a little differently from this in that its constructor is passed an owner component. And this owner is then charged with the responsibility of destroying the owned component. So that pattern looks like this:

```
component := TMyComponent.Create(OwnerComponent);
... // now component will be destroyed when OwnerComponent is destroyed
```

**Lifetime managed by interface references**

```
var
  intf: IMyInterface;
....
intf := TMyObject.Create;
DoSomething(intf);
// the implementing object behind intf is destroyed when the last 
// interface reference leaves scope
```

You cannot mix the two patterns. The design choice was made that `TComponent` would follow the first pattern. And so the interface reference counting must be disabled. By way of contrast, `TInterfacedObject` adopts the other policy.

Comment: I think in addition to your two commonly used patterns you should also mention the owner pattern, especially since it is used in TComponent what the OP refers to.

Comment: Having reread your answer I would say that TComponent does not follow the pattern in your first example (You use TMyObject in it), although it could be done, but the inherant pattern for TComponent descendants is the ownership model.

Comment: @iamjoosy Depends what is passed as the `Owner`. Pass `nil` and the caller remains as the owner. Pass something other than `nil` and that other thing becomes the owner. Fundamentally it is the same thing.

Comment: Does all these design choices meen that it is bad practice to use interfaces with forms (and any other TComponent's descendants)?

Comment: Well, you just need to be careful. And it can get messy. You need to treat an interface reference that is backed by a `TComponent` differently from other interface references. You must not retain that interface reference beyond the end of the implementing component's life. That can be difficult to arrange.